# Combine two columns data into one column leaving null values

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, sql-server-2014

i have table having four columns like this below

**Table - subscription** having data like this

```
  part_id     subscription   policylicense    enterpriselic
   part1        sub1          null                null
   part2        sub1          pl1                 null
   part3        sub1          null                enterpr1
```

I would like to get the data like this below

```
  part_id     subscription   license    
   part2        sub1          pl1                 
   part3        sub1          enterpr1
```

how to get the combined license data into one column leaving null values in the same table.. i am using sql server here

Could any one please help on this that would be very grateful to me ..
Many Thanks in advance..

Comment: @GordonLinoff both `policylicense` and `enterpriselic` are `NULL` so i guess he doesn't need that row in output

Answer (score 10):

Here is another solution using [COALESCE()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/coalesce-transact-sql)

```
SELECT
    part_id
    ,subscription
    ,COALESCE(policylicense, enterpriselic) AS license
FROM subscription
WHERE COALESCE(policylicense, enterpriselic) IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: I wasn't sure if COALESCE works on only strings or whole columns.

Comment: Works on both :)

Comment: COALESCE for more importance?

Comment: Not that if both `policylicense` and `enterpriselic` were `not null` then **license will have the value of the first one in COALESCE** meaning policylicense

Comment: @TapakahUa I ussualy use `COALESCE()` 'cause you can give a list of values to be checked; and maybe if a third column will be available you can easily just pass the column in the list of parameters.

Comment: I always take a hat with me, suddenly winter will come.

Comment: You COALESCE db engine puts it into "CASE WHEN ... END IS NOT NULL" while ISNULL or @a IS NOT NULL OR @b IS NOT NULL  final commands. You still do not understand the difference?

Answer (score 2):

```
Select 
    part_id,
    subscription,
    CONCAT(policylicense,enterpriselic) as license
from subscription where enterpriselic IS NOT NULL OR  policylicense IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: Omg... CONCAT() from sql 2012

Comment: it only got worse :) CONCAT(policylicense ,enterpriselic)

Comment: @TapakahUa : Thank you :). I was not sure about NULL value passing in `CONCAT()` . Just verified it.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT part_id, subscription,
ISNULL(policylicense, enterpriselic) AS license
FROM yourtable
WHERE policylicense IS NOT NULL OR enterpriselicense IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: Thanks for the support :)

Comment: Have a nice day ;)

Answer (score 1):

Try this. `Ternary operators`:

```
SELECT
part_id,
subscription,
IIF(policylicense IS NULL,
    IIF(enterpriselic IS NULL,'',enterpriselic),
        policylicense) as license
from subscription 
where   enterpriselic IS NOT NULL OR  
        policylicense IS NOT NULL
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this COALESC()

```
SELECT part_id
    ,subscription
    ,COALESCE(policylicense, enterpriselic) AS license
FROM subscription
WHERE COALESCE(policylicense, enterpriselic) IS NOT NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
part_id ,
subscription,   
license  = ISNULL(policylicense,enterpriselic)
FROM <table>
WHERE 
policylicense IS NOT NULL OR enterpriselic IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: While the answer is correct, please also describe in words how you came to this solution.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way using IF, so you test if the column is null or not and in having you just see the final result if null

```
SELECT part_id, subscription, IF(policylicense IS NOT NULL, policylicense, IF(enterpriselic IS NOT NULL, enterpriselic, enterpriselic)) as license
FROM tableA
HAVING license IS NOT NULL;
```